# DNS resolution Windows 7 & browsing to locally hosted web site

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-xp, windows-7, internal-dns

We host two Intranet sites, **http://intranet/** and **http://sales.intranet/**, both on the same server on the LAN.

Local DNS (a Windows 2003 Server) was updated and both hostnames are configured to be CNAMEs that point to the FQDN name of the server on which they're hosted.

On the LAN, Windows XP Professional clients can browse to both sites.

However, Windows 7 Professional clients can browse to the main Intranet site, but *not* the Sales Intranet (neither using Firefox 3 nor Internet Explorer 8).

Using nslookup on the command line on the Windows 7 boxes, **intranet** and **sales.intranet** both correctly resolve as CNAMEs of the server hosting them, and that in turn correctly resolves to the host's IP address.

So the Q is... can anyone think why this might be, or what test to try next?

Thank you for any suggestions!

---

Edit: I've since found that on the W7 clients, browsing to http://intranet.xyz/ (where xyz is the name of our Windows domain) displays the Sales Intranet.

FYI our Windows domain was set up originally as a single word, and is not in the format xxxxx.co.uk.

Also, from the W7 clients, pinging intranet.xyz works, but pinging sales.intranet.xyz doesn't.

Comment: when you ipconfig/all on the Windows 7 boxes do you see it using the proper dns server IP?

Comment: hi, yeah, there are two internal DNS servers and they're both listed, and in the right order.

Comment: How are the sites being hosted?  IIS?  What are the site configurations?  Different IPs?  Are you using host headers?

Answer (score 1):

Run a packet capture program (Wireshark, Microsoft Network Monitor, etc.) on the Windows 7 client machine and try to access the http://sales.intranet site and see what turns up in the capture. This will give you some insight into what's happening, or not happening, whichever the case may be.